# Wildcards In SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, wildcard

I want to extract rows from the table where a row should include only numeric and alphabetic characters (without accent) or characters `/ - ? : ( ) . , '' +`.

There is no restriction about the location of the characters.

I used

```
SELECT A_2 
FROM Temp_table 
WHERE A_2 LIKE [a-z0-9/-?:().,''+]%'
```

but it is not useful.

Does the `%` wildcard include all characters, numbers and special chars too?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT LIKE` with a wildcard:

```
where a_2 not like '%[^-a-zA-Z0-9/??:().,"+]%'
```

or:

```
where a_2 not like '%[^a-zA-Z0-9/??:().,"+\-]%'
```

The challenge is the hyphen, because it is a special character in the pattern.  This version uses the default escape character.